# How to copy to clipboard that each element in list will contain a new line [pyperclip]

Tags: python, pyperclip

My current input is

```
input_list = ["5155649076708", "6715439078108", "7123390204635", "6154390460085"]
```

I would like to copy element to clipboard by using pyperclip which, when copied, will be a following (so when pasting, its easier):

```
5155649076708
6715439078108
7123390204635
6154390460085
```

The above is actually the outcome using

```
for i in input_list:
    print(i)
```

Is it possible to do something like pyperclip.copy(for)) ? I've tried doing so but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try:

```
input_list = ["5155649076708", "6715439078108", "7123390204635", "6154390460085"]
pyperclip.copy("\n".join(input_list))
```